# linear independence in the dual space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

If $V$ is a $N$ dimensional vector space and $l_1,....,l_k$ are linearly independent elements of $V^*$. How to prove that map $V\to R^k$ given by $v\to (l_1(v),...,l_k(v))$ is surjective?

It does not look hard but I have problems proving it. My approach was to prove that 
$$(\ker l_1)^C\cap (\ker l_2)\cap ... \cap (\ker l_k)\neq \emptyset,$$

using dimensions argument. But it seems that dimensions do agree. Please let me know of other approaches.

Comment: I assume $k$ is some number that is $ \leq N$?

Comment: Alex, it has to be, since $\dim V^*=N$.

Answer (score 2):

If the range of your map were not all of $R^k$, there would be a non-zero vector in $R^k$ perpendicular to the range.  The components of that vector would serve as the coefficients of a linear dependence relation between the $l_i$'s, contrary to your hypothesis.

Comment: Perpendicular? Why to assume there's an inner product on a general vector space? Even if the OP meant the reals $\,\Bbb R\,$ , I don't think it is justified to assume we have anything but an abstract vector space.

Comment: The relevant inner product is not on a general vector space but on $R^k$.  Even if you don't assume (as I did, in view of the level of the question) that $R$ is the field of reals, it is clear from the question that $R$ is the field of scalars (because the $l_i(v)$ are in $R$).  So $R^k$ has a standard inner product, namely the sum of the componentwise products, and my answer works if you use this inner product.